# HTML Code - Background image

Tags: html, image, background-image

I have added some html code to a webpage to make the background stand out.  I have had to change the code for it to work on all browsers and I have now broken it, can someone please advide where I am going wrong?

```
<tr style=
"background-color: #114e64;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%, 0% 100%, color-stop(0%, #197192), color-stop(100%, #114e64));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);
background-image: linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);"
height="45">
</tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: Broken in what way? Browser broke, page broke? computer broke? :O http://jsfiddle.net/2Gw9s/

Comment: Looks fine for me >> http://jsfiddle.net/7zJBC/

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me. 
Don't forget to add a td tag to make your table cell visible.
Take a look at this jsFiddle with your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/2c8U4/

```
<table>
<tr style=
"background-color: #114e64;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%, 0% 100%, color-stop(0%, #197192), color-stop(100%, #114e64));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);
background-image: linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);"
height="45">
    <td>
        Test object
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use < td> (table columns) tag to get it working.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#114e64;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 0%, 0% 100%, color-stop(0%, #197192), color-stop(100%, #114e64));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);
background-image: linear-gradient(#197192,#114e64);"
height="45">
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

In cases like this do use the [W3C CSS Validatation Service](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input)

Convert your sample to something like this to hunt down the error:

```
 tr {background-color: #114e64;
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%,
 color-stop(0%, #197192),
 color-stop(100%, #114e64));
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#197192, #114e64);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#197192, #114e64);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#197192, #114e64);
 background-image: linear-gradient(#197192, #114e64);
}
```

Once that checks out you can convert it back to a style attribute for the HTML tag at hand.

Comment: The OP code is right, I think. It pass succesfully the validator (except, of course, the warning messages for vendor extension).

Comment: My intent was not hand out a fish but rather the tool to catch one.
If that deserves a downvote, then so be it.